# Why using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() in Blazor Wasm vs. Blazor Server are different output?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I'm creating a sample Blazor App that read a JSON file in the current project directory. I choose Blazor Webassembly and use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() which only returns '/' and not the complete path. Then, I tried to use Blazor Serverwith Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() and it shows the complete path. Well I prefer to use Blazor Wasm, but I have problem in accessing the file using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Current Result: "/"

Expected Result: "C:\Users\ROOT\Desktop\CodeMazeIntroduction\BlazorApp2"

Comment: WebAssembly runs in the browser (client). So I don't really now where the root is pointing. Blazor Server on the other hand is a .NET app and root is pointing to directory from which the app was launched

Comment: I see. @maciek do you know how to access the directory using Blazor Wasm?

Comment: In a Wasm-standalone-with-samplepages app, look at how the Weather page gets its data. You need an HttpClient.

Comment: @maciek: it is pointing at the root of an in-memory filesystem (memfs). Not very useful.

Comment: For wasm you could maybe introduce a filepicker and load the file into wasm process memory that way. I guess browsers' own file pickers provide this kind of "access" that you need. Browser is way more limited than a server which can read the actual file system of the machine on which it is run

Answer (score 3):

System.IO.File and System.IO.Directory

On Blazor Server they access the server's file system.

On Blazor WASM they access Emscripten's [MEMFS](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#memfs) which is an in memory filesystem (in the web browser's memory) created from scratch when the app loads.

By default any WASM app that was compiled by Emscripten, like Blazor WASM apps, use Emscipten's MEMFS for their file system access if they have any.

If you only need to be able to read static files, you can serve them easily from your server's wwwroot folder and access them in the client with an http request.

If you need read and write access on the server's filesystem from your Blazor WASM app, you will need create an API that allows that and access it via HTTP requests or SignalR.